# Hololens 2 emulator not recognizing inputs

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I am trying to build and deploy a basic unity project to a hololens2 emulator, however I am running into many issues:

- There is no Unity C# use checkbox in the build settings for UWP (I see this as an option in many tutorials however no one has explained how to set up for a hololens2 emulator with the newest unity versions)
- ** Main issue: The emulator itself does not recognize any inputs from the mouse/keyboard and is frozen on the start screen. Also when I try and change the setting for the inputs it is wither grayed out or the changes do not go through**

If anyone has any help they can offer that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no Unity C# use checkbox in the build settings for UWP (I see this as an option in many tutorials however no one has explained how to set up for a hololens2 emulator with the newest unity versions)

The `Unity C# Project` checkbox has been deprecated in the latest version of Unity. It used to be available when the Scripting Backend as `.Net`. But now `il2cpp` is the only available backend for the UWP platform in Unity, so this checkbox is no longer necessary.

For Unity version, we recommend the Unity LTS (Long Term Support) stream as the best version to use when starting new projects, and the current recommendation is to use Unity 2019.4.9f1: https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/lts-releases

> The emulator itself does not recognize any inputs from the mouse/keyboard and is frozen on the start screen. Also when I try and change the setting for the inputs it is wither grayed out or the changes do not go through

For Hololens-2 Emulator issue you got, I found a similar topic from the Unity forum: https://forum.unity.com/threads/hololens-2-emulator-input-controls-not-working.711713/#post-4758179 You can try the suggestions under this topic.

Comment: Thank you for this information, does that mean that C# projects are not supported or does il2cpp compensate for that?

Comment: No, the reason is il2cpp converts IL code from scripts and assemblies to C++ file, and it doesn't include your C# source scripting files in the generated solution. If you want to debug the generated cpp code, please see: [IL2CPP Internals – Debugging tips for generated code](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/20/il2cpp-internals-debugging-tips-for-generated-code/)

Comment: Hi, I believe you have checked out my answer and made some attempts based on it. Is that helping you? If it still cannot work after trying, please open a support ticket by this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport, so that we can diagnose it deeper for you.

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you used the official [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-hololens-emulator), is this correct?

Does the second point of the known issue section regarding AMD / Intel graphics apply to you? Also see the last point under Troubleshooting.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I am using this guide and thank you for those points. The emulators still does not work and I believe it is because of network connectivity issues with HyperV adapters. I am trying to use this emulator as a temporary testing environment until I receive my actual headset. Have you ever done Hololens 2 emulator work before or do you have any advice?